# How to print a String object within a String in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a String object:

```
NSString* name = @"John Smith";
```

and another String object:

```
NSString* intro =@"Hello this is ";
```

I want to be able to change the name from the UI make it within the introduction, so I tried:

```
_introduction = (@"Hello this is, %@", _name);
```

However, only the name is getting printed when I do:

```
NSlog(@"%@",_introduction);
```

I want both sentences to be printed by printing the intro object.

Comment: It's not the same question. I tried the answer included in the other question. However, the answer I was looking for is the one below.

Comment: **The** answer? There are many. Look at the second answer, it covers your question. *It's **exactly** the same question*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `(@"Hello this is, %@", _name);` does or if that's even correct syntax, but typically to do what you're trying, you'd do something like this:

```
introduction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", intro, name];
```

Comment: I thought this is how enter an object within a String. Thank you for helping.

Comment: It is in correct syntax. The komma operator `,` evaluates both operands (`@"Hello This is, %@"` and `_name`), throws away the result of the first operand and returns the result of the second operand (`_name`). The parenthesis do simply nothing. Since the first operand is side-effect free, it is simply equivalent to `introduction = _name`.